# Questions on J. F. Nash's answer about his errors in the proof of embedding theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In the interview of John Nash taken by Christian Skau and Martin Gaussen, in EMS Newsletter, September, 2015 when asked

> Is it true, as rumours have it, that
>   you started to work on the embedding problem as a result
>   of a bet?

Nash answered

> I began to work on it. Then I got shifted onto the
>   $^1$ case. It turned out that one could do it in this case
>   with very few excess dimensions of the embedding space
>   compared with the manifold. I did it with two but then
>   Kuiper did it with only one. But he did not do it smoothly,
>   which seemed to be the right thing—since you are given
>   something smooth, it should have a smooth answer.

and

> But a few years later, I made the generalisation to
>   smooth. I published it in a paper with four parts. There
>   is an error, I can confess now. Some forty years after the
>   paper was published, the logician Robert M. Solovay from
>   the University of California sent me a communication
>   pointing out the error. I thought: “How could it be?” I
>   started to look at it and finally I realized the error in
>   that if you want to do a smooth embedding and you have
>   an infinite manifold, you divide it up into portions and
>   you have embeddings for a certain amount of metric on
>   each portion. So you are dividing it up into a number of
>   things: smaller, finite manifolds. But what I had done was
>   a failure in logic. I had proved that—how can I express
>   it?—that points local enough to any point where it was
>   spread out and differentiated perfectly if you take points
>   close enough to one point; but for two different points
>   it could happen that they were mapped onto the same
>   point.

My question is:

1- What did Nash mean by very few excess dimensions of the embedding space compared with the manifold? It means that the they can do it in the case the dimension of the embedding space is a little bit greater than the dimension of the manifold, doesn't it?

2- What did Nash mean by his generalization to smooth?

3- What did Nash mean by a certain amout of metric on each portion? Does this mean that each portion has some different metrics?

4- What did Nash mean by "I had proved that that points local enough to any point where it was spread out and differentiated perfectly if you take points close enough to one point"? How can a point spread out and differentiated?

Please explain for me.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Nash-Kuiper proves that if $M$ (possibly not compact) smoothly embeds in $\Bbb R^k$, then there is also a $C^1$ isometric embedding into $\Bbb R^k$: you don't need to add on more dimensions for wiggle room to get the isometric embedding. 2) Nash proved that there exists a smooth isometric embedding into some large Euclidean space. I don't know about his error, so I can't say precisely for which manifolds it's true, but based on the discussion above I would guess the main trouble is noncompact manifolds.

Comment: I do not know about the mistake but it sounds like the trouble was proving that the map is an embedding rather than an immersion.

Comment: This question was cross posted to MathOverflow where [I gave an answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/242100/3948).